# Uniquely identify each client, execute queries and send send client specific notification Nodejs socket.io cakephp

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Trying to send unique identifier to server on connect so that a user specific query can be executed and client specific notification be returned.

Client connection:

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8990',{query:"unique_identifier=some_number"});`

Server:

`io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {
console.log(socket.handshake);
console.log(socket.handshake.query.unique_identifier);`

Console log for unique identifier says undefined

Unable to get the unique_identifier in the server file.
Then I want to pass this unique_identifier to a function to execute sql query and update that specific socket.

Comment: what is the output of your console log

Comment: Console log displays undefined for unique_identifier and the normal handshake parameters for socket.handshake. Edited post to add this.